# How do I initialise assets using the SFML library in C++?

Tags: c++, object, compiler-errors

I've been working on a simpe tank game as a project in SFML.
It's my first time using this library and I am having some problems while creating an object of Assets:

Game header:

```
class Game
{
Assets as;
}
```

Assets header:

```
Class Assets
{ 
 Assets() {
    loadTextures();
    loadSprites();
} 
public:
    Texture t1;
    Sprite s1;
public:
    void loadTextures();
    void loadSprites();
}
```

Assets cpp file:

```
 void Assets::loadTextures()
{
if (!t1.loadFromFile("images/tank.png"))
    cout << "Error 42 - File not found " << endl;
}

void Assets::loadSprites()
{
    s1.setTexture(t1);
}
```

And the main function in Source.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
Game game;

return 0;
}
```

And I've got an error and 2 notes. 
Error : 'Game::Game(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

note: compiler has generated 'Game::Game' here

note: 'Game::Game(void)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'Assets::Assets(void)'

All of them appear as soon as I try to intitialize the Assets object and I've got no idea why.

Comment: You error message says `Game` has a base class, but I'm not seeing one in your post.  Does `Game` have a base class?

Comment: No there is only 1 game class.

Comment: And it doesn't inherit from anything?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code directly?  Because I see numerous syntax errors that make it difficult to try and run what you have.  Capital C in class, missing semicolons at the end of a class definition, Assets constructor needs to be public.  Provide us with the exact code trimmed down so we can see what's going on properly.

Comment: BTW your likely problem is that Assets default constructor is private.  This makes it inaccessible by Game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets default constructor is private, ensure it's public.

Game has an Assets object as a member.  This gets default constructed when Game is created.  The default constructor is private, and therefore the assets object cannot be created.